# Detect and convert a file with Unix line ending to windows with PHP?

Tags: php, line-endings

What is the best way to detect if a file has Unix style line endings (`\r\n`) programatically in PHP and if file has Unix line endings convert the file to Windows style line endings (`\n`)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows command to convert Unix line endings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17579553/windows-command-to-convert-unix-line-endings)

Comment: Look this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11066857/detect-eol-type-using-php

Comment: You have those back to front; it's Windows with `\r\n`.

Comment: how far had you tried?

Comment: Actually, it's LF for Unix, CR for Macintosh and CRLF for MS Windows.